# Magento 2 Dropdown dialog like as minicart

Tags: magento2

How to setup a Dropdown Dialog like as mini cart, I would like to use these type Dropdown dialog for my custom menu located in a .phtml file.

Anyone show me an example please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reuse the authentication dropdown from the checkout page to achieve this effect:

```
<div class="authentication-wrapper" data-block="authentication">
    <button
        type="button"
        class="action action-auth-toggle"
        data-trigger="authentication">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Click Me'"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="block-authentication"
         style="display: none"
         data-bind="mageInit: {
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal':{
                'type': 'custom',
                'modalClass': 'authentication-dropdown',
                'trigger': '[data-trigger=authentication]',
                'wrapperClass': 'authentication-wrapper',
                'parentModalClass': '_has-modal-custom _has-auth-shown',
                'responsive': true,
                'responsiveClass': 'custom-slide',
                'overlayClass': 'dropdown-overlay modal-custom-overlay',
                'buttons': []
            }}">
        <div>
            HELLO!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You will probably want to replace the `authentication-wrapper` css class because it has a `float: right` property. The only requirement here is that the class be relative or absolute positioned. You also need to change the `wrapperClass` configuration option to match yours.

Comment: Thanks Aron, Its really worked well, also I used additional css class to modalClass like this
`'modalClass': 'authentication-dropdown custom-class',`
So it more easy to customize!

Comment: Hi Aron, I noticed `'responsive': true,` to enable responsive slide from right that really nice feature.
Can we use this same method for mini-cart too? so in small screen it will more handy.